# Dynamically need to add page break in RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

Here I am using two sub reports (subreport1,subreport2)in the list, some time shows subreport1 and some time show subreport2 and sometimes both will disable in that time Empty page was printing becoz of given pageBreak after the list, I dono need to add pagebreak if the both subreport are empty,

Please help,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work set KeepTogether property as False